# How to connect from MS SSMS to PostgreSQL database?

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssms, odbc

Can someone tell me what the provider string looks like when trying to connect from MS SSMS to PostgreSQL database via linked server?

[image]

Comment: Created DSN like here https://www.sqlshack.com/configure-odbc-drivers-for-postgresql/ Connection successful. However, when using that DSN in MS SSMS for creating linked server, iz says wrong password?! Wierd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Created DSN (data source name) with `ODBC Data Source Administrator (64-bit)` tool. Named it *PostgreSQLW31*. In it, I used `PostgreSQL Unicode(x64)` driver and data like username, password, port, database, server. Tested connection with a `test connection` button. I used that *PostgreSQLW31* data source name instead of the provider string in SSMS. You can use one or the other.

After that in SSMS, right click on server link created earlier, serurity, and then add `Local server login to remote server login mappings`. Add local SQL user, add remote db user and pass and it works.

[link](https://blog.pythian.com/fix-sql-server-to-postgresql-linked-server-error-requested-conversion-is-not-supported/) for casting not supported data types

Edit: I succeeded to connect with this data provider (connection string): `Provider=MSDASQL; DRIVER=PostgreSQL Unicode(x64); SERVER=my_server_ip; DATABASE=my_db; UID=my_user; PWD=my_pass`

Comment: As a side note: [ConnectionStrings.com](https://www.connectionstrings.com/) is a wonderful collection of all kinds of DB connections.